# Chromedriver - selected locale not accepted while headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

Chromedriver doesn't seem to accept locale while in `headless` mode. Without headless it uses `pl` even without specifing it (it's default language for Chrome on my OS). How can I force it to work?

```
default: {
      launch_url: 'https://nightwatchjs.org',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
        chromeOptions: {
          prefs: {
            "intl.accept_languages":"pl"
          },
          args: [
            `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3`,
            // "--window-size=640,1136" // iphone 5
            "window-size=1920,1080",
            "headless",
          ],
          w3c: false
        },
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
      }
    },
```

Comment: try with ChromeOptions and AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", language); https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions_AddUserProfilePreference.htm

Comment: @pcalkins That's exactly what I did - it's even in my code example in the question

Comment: looks like you are using prefs... I think the more recent versions of chromedriver have moved those into ChromeOptions methods.

Comment: @pcalkins could you provide example? Not sure what do you have in mind

Comment: haven't used Selenium with javascript before... not sure how you'd call a class method in JS.

Comment: So I can't use it in a static configuration? I have to call a method?

Comment: not sure... just figured it would be something to try.  It may not be the problem at all.  Especially if it's working when you remove the headless flag.  (That would be the same chromedriver...)

Comment: When I don't use `headless` then it shows normally `pl` locale - that's the part I don't get

Comment: See Chromium bug discussion here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=755338